# How can I get geometry from Google Fusion To Google Map API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I've created a table in Google Fusion from shape file (converted to kml). I can show the geometry of all rows in Google Maps v3. But the problem is I can't filter the geometry (here is boundary of countries) by country's name.

I've followed the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-query) but it looks like that **ignores the where clause**.

Here is my sample code, I hope someone will help me to filter geometry by name.

Another question: What is the result of Fusion Table query? Is it JSON type, and how can I get it?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fusion Tables layers</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #map-canvas {width: 1000px; height: 600px}
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
var map, layer;

function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(33.420, 106.514);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: chicago,
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
     select: 'geometry',
      from: '1emmdckIBQOQbTa9fik0naDOWGhnK4o3Xo_XRiys',
      where: '"Name" = "Viet Nam"'
    //query: "select geometry from 1emmdckIBQOQbTa9fik0naDOWGhnK4o3Xo_XRiys where name = China"
    }
  });
  layer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tmEX/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (inverted the ' and "):

```
  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
     select: 'geometry',
      from: '1emmdckIBQOQbTa9fik0naDOWGhnK4o3Xo_XRiys',
      where: "'Name' = 'Viet Nam'"
    }
  });
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLC5d/4/embedded/result/)